# MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION not work on devices: Samsung and LG

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

and onActivityRezult:

```
Uri uri;
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ATTACH_SOUND) {
                uri = (Uri) data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
                if (Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI.equals(uri)) {
                    uri = null;
                }
            } else {
                uri = data.getData();
            }
```

On the simulator and htc is working fine. But on Samsung and LG not work, RECORD app returns nothing. What is the problem?

Comment: i don't really see how RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI would be the extra for recording a sound

Comment: i not undarstand you. What do you mean?

Comment: I don't see how "uri = (Uri) data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
" would get you the recorded sound. does it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also not sure how or why are you using Extra ringtone thing...

Just try This, call the recorder, here the code is 1 for this example...

```
public void RecordAudio(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1); // intent and requestCode of 1

}
```

And to receive the audio use this,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{     if (requestCode == 1) {
        // is the resultCode OK?
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              // lets get the uri
            Uri audioUri = data.getData();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Reply from Recorder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              // lets do something with it.
              // functiontodsomethingAudio(audioUri);
          }
      }
```

It worked for me... I found the code in a book, *its not mine!*